# How to convert UTC time format to Date in Java

Tags: java, date, utc

I have to call a web service which is expecting a Date field but they want it in the following format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ. How can I do this?

I tried the following

```
OffsetDateTime transactionTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

Date.from(transactionTime.toInstant());
```

but this didn't work. transactionTime is 2021-06-01T15:11:09.942843400Z, but Date.from converts it to Tue Jun 01 11:11:09 EDT 2021.

BTW, I'm using Java 11

Comment: 2021-06-01T15:11:09.942843400Z (Zulu, Greenwich time) **is** 2021-06-01T11:11:09.942843400 EDT. It is the same instant at different timezones.

Comment: "Date.from converts it to Tue Jun 01 11:11:09 EDT 2021" - no, `Date.from` converts it to a `Date` object, which isn't a string. If you need to format a `Date` object in a particular way, there are various approaches to that (e.g. `SimpleDateFormat`).

Comment: `java.util.Date` does not have the concept of timezone. The string, `Tue Jun 01 11:11:09 EDT 2021` represents the date-time in your timezone. Since `Date` does not have timezone information, it applies the JVM's timezone to return the value of `Date#toString`.

Comment: A `Date` also cannot have a format.

Comment: What makes you think that you want a `Date`? That class is poorly designed and long outdated, and web services don’t consume `Date` objects directly, so you should not want one. Better to stick to your `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

See that code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Uu6uwp).

> 2021-06-01T15:21:16.783779Z

That format is defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The `Z` on end means an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Pronounced “Zulu”.

Use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) to represent a moment as seen in UTC.

Going the other direction, from text to object.

```
Instant.parse( "2021-06-01T15:21:16.783779Z" )
```

If you want only milliseconds, you can lop off any microseconds and nanoseconds by [truncating](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS ) ;
```

Never use the legacy `Date` class. Use only the  *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 2):

### Use `DateTimeFormatter` to format the Date-Time object

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime transactionTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        String formatted = transactionTime.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-01T15:49:45.198Z
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### What if I want to use `java.util.Date`?

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `OffsetDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(transactionTime.toInstant());
```

Note that a `java.util.Date` object is not a real Date-Time object like the [modern Date-Time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). Since `Date` does not have timezone information, it applies the JVM's timezone to return the value of `Date#toString` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the Date-Time in a different format and timezone, you will need to use a `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the timezone set to the applicable one e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String strDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(strDate);
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-01T15:49:45.198Z
```

**Some other important notes:**

1. The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.
2. Most of the symbols that you have used in `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ` are wrong. Check the description of the symbols from the documentation pages of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>